# Python: install some packages

Tags: python, package, pip

I need to advice:
I have 2 versions of Python: 2 and 3.
How Can I install some package through the `pip` to especially version? What should I use?

Comment: You should create 2 `virtualenv`, install Python 2 in one of them and Python 3 in the second.

Comment: Are you working on Linux or windows?

Comment: You should try installing anaconda so you don't have any versioning problem...

Comment: @Giordano windows

Comment: @MohamedALANI I don't like spyder, because it has 
inconvenient code completion

Comment: You don't need to use spyder ! anaconda will just install some usual python tools. You can unistall spyder if you wish. I personnally use jupyter notebook or atom.

Comment: @PetrPetrov Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.x: In `C:\Python27\Scripts` folder you will have some executables like `pip2.7.exe` or `pip2.exe` 
similarly for Python 3.x.

`cmd> pip install <module>`
instead of just `pip` you can use the respected version of `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Each version of python has a corresponding version of pip so you run specific versions of pip corresponding to your versions of Python. Example :

```
pip3.5 install packagename 
pip2.7 install packagename
```

And if your using an IDE like PyCharm,you can easy install packages of in specific versions of Python from settings environment.Go to `project settings>project interpreter>choose the version of python you want to install in>click the plus (+) sign >`now search the package you want to install my typing in the search bar.Once you find it,click install.

You can also run Pythons venv.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work. it returns me `no matching distribution found for telebot`. I'm trying to install `telebot`. I use IDE PyCharm and there are not packages in list, connected with telebot. I've tried to install it through the pip, it installed successfully, but in python 3 in pycharm I get `No package telebot`

Comment: There is away in Pycharm.

Comment: @Petr Petrov. Check my answer,I edited it.For pycharm

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed two python versions you should have also two different Scripts folders that contain the respective pip. So you can go in the correct one and install the package that you want.

If you have a pip version >= 0.8 and < 1.5, you can also specify the pip version that you want use.

For example:

```
pip-2.7 install package
```

If you are using a pip version >= 1.5 the syntax is different; you can proceed in this way:

```
pip2.7 install package
```

Another possibility, if you are using an IDE, is install the package directly inside it.

I have read in a comment that you are using PyCharm, so you can go to

`settings->Project->project interpreter`

Check that the selected interpreter is the correct one and click on plus icon in the right corner.

Choose the package and click to install.

Let me know.